# Can't connect to mac in visual studio

Tags: macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to connect to mac in visual studio.

I did every step and I also connected to the Xamarin account.

In the Xamarin Mac Agent it found the mac which means I did the steps.

So sharing preferences are correctly configured at mac.

But when I try to connect to mac, after entering username and password it shows the following error:

> Couldn't connect to MacBook.local. Please try again.

I don't know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: What does the output window say? Is everything up to date (Xamarin VS **and** Xamarin Mac)? What have you done so far?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe The instruction didn't ask to have Xamarin for Mac. I only have Xamarin installed in visual studio. It only needs Mac to pair and connect with it.

Comment: You need to install Xamarin on your Mac as well. It will install the buildhost and some other tools Visual Studio will connect to.

Comment: You don't need buildhost anymore. Did you enable connections on MAC per instructions? If you did all instructions check xamarin log files.

Answer (score 2):

The Xamarin.iOS SDK and Xcode both need to be installed on the Mac you're trying to connect to. See [Installing Xamarin.iOS on Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#System_Requirements)  and the step-by-step [installation guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/).

Once Xamarin is installed on both Mac and PC, you can check the log files for hints about any connectivity issues you may encounter.

- Mac – ~/Library/Logs/Xamarin-[MAJOR.MINOR]
- Windows – %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs

You may also find the [Connection Troubleshooting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/)  and general [diagnostic info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/) guides helpful.